# Usar un objeto a nivel global Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

He creado un recurso con su respectivo modelo y controlador, en el cual busco personalizar el estilo del sitio, en el cual modifico el valor del attributo y al cambiarse cambie el estilo de ciertos elementos del sitio por ejemplo:

```
<nav class="header" style="background: <%= @setting.header_color %><% else %>">
```

Sin embargo, aunque si bien funciona en las vistas del mismo recurso no funciona fuera de el, ya que obtengo un error nil, y quería me ayudasen a poder utilizarlo independientemente de la vista, talvez declarando algo en application controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decláralo con un `:before_action` en el ApplicationController, con eso te funcionará en todas las vistas de todos los controladores:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb    
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :fetch_settings

  def fetch_settings
    @settings = current_user.settings
  end
end
```

Comment: y en la vista como podría llamarlo Danirod? o Desde luego normal solo llamando al objeto y luego su atributo?

Comment: Al motor de vistas le llegan todas las variables que empiezan por una arroba que hayan sido declaradas en alguno de los métodos del controlador, por lo que cuando el método fetch_settings es ejecutado en el ApplicationController, desde cualquier vista puedes usar (@)settings, incluyendo el <%= (@)settings.header_color %> tal como tienes en tu pregunta.

Comment: Te entiendo Danirod, tu definistes el metodo como fetch_settings y eso es independiente de la vista en la que me encuentre? ya que comunmente defino un metodo como index, show, etc y solo en esas se puede ver, pero en este caso podria verse en todas?

Comment: Eso mismo. El before_action te permite ejecutar código de otras funciones antes que el del index/show... Se suele usar para favorecer el no repetirse (DRY) haciendo que bloques de código idénticos que deben ejecutarse en varios controladores (como un Post.find en show, edit, update y destroy) sólo se escriban una vez en vez de cuatro. Si lo pones en el ApplicationController, cualquier controlador que extienda de ApplicationController lo ejecutará también.

Comment: Te entiendo Daniro, una pregunta mas, ya que no he llegado a casa y no he tenido oportunidad de probarlo, segun veo, el metodo solo se ejecutara si hay un usuario actua, eso puedo cambiarlo por un Setting.all?

Comment: Oh, no, si lo dices por ese current_user que he puesto en mi código respuesta, disculpa si lo he hecho confuso o incorrecto. He puesto una línea de código de ejemplo inventada para mostrar que puedes hacer la asignación a falta de saber de dónde sale tu setting, aunque de cara a la respuesta da igual porque es lo mismo siempre. Ahí puede ir el mismo código que has usado para obtener las settings en tu recurso inicial.

Comment: Va genialisimo Danirod! te agradezco mucho!